# Html5 application cache

Tags: html, html5-appcache

I tried to work with Html5 app cache for run my application in offline mode.
For this, I created test.html file and demo.appcache

In this html page, i'm using some images from local host. When my local host is running, it's working fine. But, if i tried to stop the local host , the images are not getting from my app cache. out put simply displays as empty page.

Here is my sampletest.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html manifest="demo.appcache">

<head>
</head>

<body>
Further modified........Test Again
<img src="http://172.17.0.238/SampleImages/two.jpg" width="225" height="151" alt="Milford Sound in New Zealand" />

</body></html>
```

demo.appcache

```
CACHE MANIFEST
CACHE:
sampletest.html
NETWORK:
```

FALLBACK:

Is there any wrong in my code. Under CACHE: i loaded my html file. But , when the local host not available, it doesn't load the html from app cache.

Any help...
Regards,
Lokesh.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include all the resources needed by you page in the manifest: images, external javascript and css, and so on.

Comment: already i included css, js files in demo.appcache under CACHE, But no use, still the out put is same. for that i just loaded my html alone in locally. But it was not working..

Comment: If the host is available, my sampletest.html will be loaded the images from the local host, and store that file in locally. When the host went to offline, it will take the html file from app cache. This is expecting from my code. IS it right with my code or any change..?? need clarification..

Comment: Did you include images in the cache, as I've said ?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. In my case I'm using the WevView in an Android device. There it just needs 9 minutes to register that the host is not reachable - then it loads from appcache. I don't know if other agents behave like that, but it's worth a try ;)

---

Anyway: you don't have to declare the CACHE section if its the first entry:

```
   CACHE MANIFEST
   sampletest.html
   NETWORK:
```

only if you want to add more content to be cached after you used NETWORK or FALLBACK:

```
   CACHE MANIFEST
   sampletest.html

   NETWORK:
   *

   FALLBACK:
   online.html offline.html

   CACHE:
   additionalContent.html
```

But please don't ask my why they decided that this has to be possible ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing is mainly due to the fact of different error codes depending on the situation.
If your computer does not have internet access, it won't try to reach the server and will try to load from the appcache.

The problem is when your computer has access to the internet, and you turn off the server, then the error is different (it will return probably 4xx or 5xx or equivalent). It is a server problem and not a user problem, therefore it will fail to load the cache.

> Otherwise, if fetching the manifest fails in some other way (e.g. the server returns another 4xx or 5xx response or equivalent, or there is a DNS error, or the connection times out, or the user cancels the download, or the parser for manifests fails when checking the magic signature), or if the server returned a redirect, or if the resource is labeled with a MIME type other than text/cache-manifest, then run the cache failure steps.

This is documented here:
http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/offline.html#downloading-or-updating-an-application-cache